# Represent standard inner product with respect to a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Represent the standard inner product in $R^3$ with respect to the basis ${(1,0,1),(0,1,1), (1,-2,3)}.$

This question is from the book Elements of Differential Geometry. I don not really understand what the question is asking. I've taken a linear algebra class and I know the definition of inner product and basis, but I'm confused on what it means to represent the inner product with respect to the basis.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathcal{B} = \left( b_1,b_2,b_3 \right)$ be a basis of $R^3$, and let $\langle \ldotp,\ldotp \rangle$ denote the inner product. A representation of $\langle \ldotp,\ldotp \rangle$ with respect to $\mathcal{B}$ is the following transformation matrix:
$$
\mathrm{M}_\mathcal{B}(\langle \ldotp,\ldotp \rangle) =
\begin{pmatrix}
  \langle b_1,b_1 \rangle & \langle b_1,b_2 \rangle & \langle b_1,b_3 \rangle \\
  \langle b_2,b_1 \rangle & \langle b_2,b_2 \rangle & \langle b_2,b_3 \rangle \\
  \langle b_3,b_1 \rangle & \langle b_3,b_2 \rangle & \langle b_3,b_3 \rangle \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$